# Statistical Analysis with chars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm wondering how to make an analysis with chars in R, specifically with a barplot or ggPlot. If I have a read excel file that contains a list like below, how could I make a barplot with it since the data is not in chars to count the number of occurrences the name appears in a bar plot?

```r
Most Popular Names
John
Tim
John
Tim
Cole
Cody
```

Comment: Get the frequency and plot, for example: `barplot(table(mtcars$cyl))`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the frequency of each name in column 'Most Popular Names' with the `table()` function. This data can be used to build up a barplot.

```
data <- data.frame(`Most Popular Names` = c("John", "Tim", "John", "Tim", "Cole","Cody"))
barplot(table(data))
```